# How to access excel file columns in for loop in R?

Tags: r

I have a excel file where there are some columns filled with numerical value. I want to find out the standard deviation of each column. How to code in R for that?

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 0):

We can use `readxl` to read the excel data and then with `summarise` from `dplyr`, get the `sd` `across` columns that are `numeric`

```
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
out <- read_excel('file.xlsx') %>%
     summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sd, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Other simple option is first convert your excel file into csv file and save in your working directory, and then use following code:

```
data <- read.csv("file.csv") #read csv file
out <- apply(data, 2, FUN = function(x) sd(x, na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Not all of the columns are numeric. You should identify those columns before calculating `sd`

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following base R code works for you

```
Filter(
  Negate(is.na),
  lapply(
    read_excel("file.xlsx"),
    function(x) ifelse(is.numeric(x), sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), NA)
  )
)
```